# How can i set setCapability testName become cucumber scenario

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, appium

how i can set cucumber scenario become testName in setCapability

```
  DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();

  @BeforeMethod
  public void setUp() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    dc.setCapability("reportDirectory", reportDirectory);
    dc.setCapability("reportFormat", reportFormat);
    dc.setCapability("testName",cucumberScenario());}
```

I already try scenario.getName() and scenario.getSourceTagName;
but always get value null

Comment: `DesiredCapabilities` is Selenium api, why would it care what the test name is?

Comment: cause i want to get name scenario become test name in my report, i using appium studio report

Comment: Please share the code of `cucumberScenario()`. Thanks

Comment: Even if you could add it to `DesiredCapabilities`, it won't help you adding it to the report. There is no connection between the webdriver and the reporter. I don't know which reporter you are using, but usually the file or test method names are being used automatically.

Comment: cucumberScenario just example, i already try with scenario.getName() and scenario.getSourceTagName but getting null value @ZainUlAbideen

Answer (score 2):

Add **Scenario scenario** in the method parameter.

Try this

```
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities(); 

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp(Scenario scenario) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
dc.setCapability("reportDirectory", reportDirectory);
dc.setCapability("reportFormat", reportFormat);
dc.setCapability("testName",scenario.getName());}
```